# jquery above and below screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a script for showing a div before different divs in different screen size. This is the code I used:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).on('resize', function(){
        if(jQuery(window).width() <= 1024){
            jQuery( ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-shipping-fields__wrapper" ).insertBefore( ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .flux-step.flux-step--2 .flux-checkout__shipping-table" );
        }
        else if(jQuery(window).width() >= 1025){
            jQuery( ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-shipping-fields__wrapper" ).insertBefore( ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .flux-checkout__content-right #order_review" );
        }
    }); 
}); 
});
```

But the code is not working when I open the site. It only works if I resize the screen. May be due to the resize function is used.

Can anyone please guide me how to make it so that it'll show the 2 conditions even without resizing the screen and one'll work above 1024px and another below 1024px.

TIA

Comment: I would strongly suggest you rethink this approach. Best practice would be to inject the same HTML structure and then position it using CSS based on screen size, if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your code in a function and call it on the document ready:

```js
$(function(){
  
  resize();
  
  $(window).on('resize', resize);

  function resize(){
    $( ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-shipping-fields__wrapper" )
      .insertBefore(
        $(window).width() <= 1024 ? 
        ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .flux-step.flux-step--2 .flux-checkout__shipping-table" : 
        ".checkout.woocommerce-checkout .flux-checkout__content-right #order_review"
      );
   }
   
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alexander.. That worked exactly how I wanted. Thank you verymuch.